# Android simulate low data signal strength

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm having some trouble with an application with our users complaining that under low signal strength, they're having issues with using the app. Is there any way I can simulate this on an emulator?

Thanks, 
Teja.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know in DDMS in the Emulator Control tab, there's a section at the top where you can set the data/voice limitations. Maybe setting data to EDGE or something similar would do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

Would setting to 'Airplane Mode' help ?

Comment: That's completely different