# Fake Poor Internet

Tags: android, iphone

I'm trying to test my iPhone and Android application with poor internet. I remember there was a program I read about a while back that would fake different types of poor internet. Does anyone remember what this program was called or if there is something similar I can use to accomplish this task?

Comment: Have you checked the simulator options? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045136/android-simulate-low-data-signal-strength

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/330501/simulate-limited-bandwidth-from-within-firefox looks like it might help.

Comment: @BoltClock This is dealing with a mobile application and a web service. So those that are developing with PHP and JavaScript have the same need.

Comment: I found http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/proxying/throttling/

Answer (score 17):

For iOS, as others have said, use the Network Link Conditioner settings under Settings > Developer > Network Link Conditioner.

**For Android, just because nobody mentioned this...**

- use your iOS device to set up a personal hotspot
- connect your Android device to the iOS hotspot
- I put the Android device into Airplane mode, and then re-enable WiFi (or turn off cellular data, but I find these settings quicker for me to access on my device)
- Use the iOS device's Network Link Conditioner settings to adjust the quality of the network

Since the Android device is tunneling through the iOS device's network, it'll be effected by the iOS device's network link conditioner settings.

Super easy, super awesome, and configurable.

Comment: Another way is enable Network Link Conditioner on mac and make mac wi-fi hotspot

Comment: Ha, true.. but then you have to deal with sucky internet on your mac ;)  But... if you don't have an extra iOS device, the mac suggestion is great too

Answer (score 11):

The one that I use and recommend is [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/).  You set it up so that your iPhone or Android uses it as the proxy.  Then it can [throttle your connection](http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/proxying/throttling/)  to simulate poor network conditions like 3G.

It has a lot of other useful features like being able to track and inspect all your HTTP requests and responses which is really helpful when writing apps that access web services.

Comment: Seconded for Charles.  Another option is WebScarab NG (free, but Charles is totally worth the purchase price)

Answer (score 2):

For your iOS applications, Apple has a program called Network Link Conditioner for free for Lion users as part of xCode. For your Android apps, you can probably use Netlimiter.

Netlimiter: http://www.netlimiter.com/

Answer (score 1):

A strategy to fake poor internet could be to open up sockets and send data as quickly as you can - the more threads that are doing this, the more of your device's internet access will be taken up, thus leaving less for the app. For example: if you have 1 other thread sending data, your bandwidth will be halved; if you have 3 other threads, only a quarter will be left for your application, and so on...

I imagine that this is the strategy employed by the program about which you read (although there are other ways in which this could be accomplished).

Answer (score 0):

There's the Apple Link Conditioner which is included with all recent installs of the developer tools. It'll be in system preferences once it's installed.