# How to simulate low bandwidth (network delay) in localhost ( running on WAMP, Windows XP)?

Tags: wamp

How to simulate  low bandwidth (network delay) in localhost ( running on wamp, windows XP) ? I was looking to set it on the server-side not on the client-side.

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094760/network-tools-that-simulate-slow-network-connection

Comment: Take a look at my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9742828/fake-poor-internet/9742918#9742918  If you use Charles Proxy, then you can direct multiple clients to it.  Then you can throttle them all to simulate poor bandwidth, as well as see every request that gets sent.

Comment: Thanks for both. I was looking for something like configuring WAMP to simulate the delay without having to install anything. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this by using a module for Apache called [Bandwidth Mod](http://ivn.cl/2010/01/06/downloads-for-bandwidth-mod/#bandwidth). Even though this version is for Apache 2.2.14, I am using it on 2.2.21 without any problems.

Grab the [bw_mod.dll](http://ivn.cl/files/dlls/mod_bw-0.91-2.2.14/mod_bw.dll) file from the link above, and put it into the Apache modules folder (usually `bin\Apache\Apache2.2.xx\modules` in your Wampserver installation folder) and then add this to your `httpd.conf` file:

```
LoadModule bw_module modules/mod_bw.dll
BandWidthModule On
ForceBandWidthModule On
BandWidth    all 50000
MinBandWidth all -1
```

Be sure to check out the [readme file](http://legacy.ivn.cl/files/txt/mod_bw-0.92.txt) for this module as it comes with a lot of options.

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 1):

This is a recipe for Apache 2.2.x on FreeBSD for your own LAN server, meaning you have access to the *apache.conf* file.

Unfortunately, `mod_bw` does not work with .htaccess files (yet) so easy and fast testing with various speeds in not possible that way. But here is a workaround that works fine for me.

Install mod_bw on FreeBSD...

```
# cd /usr/ports/www/mod_bw
# make install clean
```

Make a speed dir in your document root...

```
# cd /path/to/doc/root
# mkdir _s
```

Make symbolic links in that speed dir to the document root...

```
# cd _s
# ln -s /path/to/doc/root 33k
# ln -s /path/to/doc/root 56k
# ln -s /path/to/doc/root 128k
# ln -s /path/to/doc/root 256k
# ln -s /path/to/doc/root 512k
# ln -s /path/to/doc/root 1024k
```

Edit `/usr/local/etc/apache22/httpd.conf` and make these line occur...

```
LoadModule bw_module libexec/apache22/mod_bw.so

<Directory "/path/to/doc/root">
    Options FollowSymLinks
</Directory>

<directory /path/to/doc/root/_s/33k>
    <ifmodule mod_bw.c>
        BandWidthModule On
        ForceBandWidthModule On
        Bandwidth all 33000
    </ifmodule>
</directory>
<directory /path/to/doc/root/_s/56k>
    <ifmodule mod_bw.c>
        BandWidthModule On
        ForceBandWidthModule On
        Bandwidth all 56000
    </ifmodule>
</directory>
<directory /path/to/doc/root/_s/128k>
    <ifmodule mod_bw.c>
        BandWidthModule On
        ForceBandWidthModule On
        Bandwidth all 128000
    </ifmodule>
</directory>
<directory /path/to/doc/root/_s/256k>
    <ifmodule mod_bw.c>
        BandWidthModule On
        ForceBandWidthModule On
        Bandwidth all 256000
    </ifmodule>
</directory>
<directory /path/to/doc/root/_s/512k>
    <ifmodule mod_bw.c>
        BandWidthModule On
        ForceBandWidthModule On
        Bandwidth all 512000
    </ifmodule>
</directory>
<directory /path/to/doc/root/_s/1024k>
    <ifmodule mod_bw.c>
        BandWidthModule On
        ForceBandWidthModule On
        Bandwidth all 1024000
    </ifmodule>
</directory>
```

Restart apache...

```
# apachectl restart
```

That's it! You can access your LAN website the usual way with LAN speed or with a selected speeds...

E.g.

- `http://serverip/website_name/`
- `http://serverip/_s/56k/website_name/`

Goodluck!

P.S.
Your website need to be designed such that it will always run whether it is located in document root or in any sub directory.